# Parsing an XML bug report dataset into CSV using Python when there are duplicate tags

Tags: python, xml

I hava a bug report dataset in XML format from a repository outside of my control.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<short_desc>
  <report id="756550">
    <update> #first update
      <when>1337336250</when>
      <what>Alias is resolved to a bug number for a private bug</what>
    </update>
    <update> #latest update
      <when>1344175272</when>
      <what>Do not link a bug alias with its bug ID for bugs you cannot see</what>
    </update>
  </report>
</short_desc>
```

I'm looking to get the following output in a CSV file:

```
id       description
756550   Alias is resolved to a bug number for a private bug
756550   Do not link a bug alias with its bug ID for bugs you cannot see
```

I've tried using Elementtree in Python, but I can only retrieve the contents of the  tags without its corresponding report ID.

Can someone help me solve this? Thx

Comment: You should at least show (a piece of code) what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

What it does is it parses the xml with the xml package of python.

Find the nodes of interest through xpath expression.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<short_desc>
  <report id="756550">
    <update> #first update
      <when>1337336250</when>
      <what>Alias is resolved to a bug number for a private bug</what>
    </update>
    <update> #latest update
      <when>1344175272</when>
      <what>Do not link a bug alias with its bug ID for bugs you cannot see</what>
    </update>
  </report>
</short_desc>"""


root = ET.fromstring(data)

whens = root.findall(".//when")
whats = root.findall(".//what")

for id, desc in zip(whens, whats):
    print(id.text, desc.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the `id` by accessing the element's attributes by key, e.g., `report['id']`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import BytesIO

data = b'''\
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<short_desc>
  <report id="756550">
    <update> #first update
      <when>1337336250</when>
      <what>Alias is resolved to a bug number for a private bug</what>
    </update>
    <update> #latest update
      <when>1344175272</when>
      <what>Do not link a bug alias with its bug ID for bugs you cannot see</what>
    </update>
  </report>
</short_desc>
'''

print("id      description")

f = BytesIO(data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
for report in soup.select('report'):
    id_ = report['id']
    for what in report.select('what'):
        print(f"{id_:<7} {what.text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create list of tuples and do what you like with it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<short_desc>
  <report id="756550">
    <update> #first update
      <when>1337336250</when>
      <what>Alias is resolved to a bug number for a private bug</what>
    </update>
    <update> #latest update
      <when>1344175272</when>
      <what>Do not link a bug alias with its bug ID for bugs you cannot see</what>
    </update>
  </report>
</short_desc>"""


root = ET.fromstring(data)
data = [(e.find('when').text,e.find('what').text) for e in root.findall('.//update')]
print(data)
```

output

```
[('1337336250', 'Alias is resolved to a bug number for a private bug'), ('1344175272', 'Do not link a bug alias with its bug ID for bugs you cannot see')]
```